# How to set occurrence of a user entry in SQL?

Tags: sql

This is how I want to set a flag, how to do it in SQL?

| User | Payment | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 1500 | 1 |
| U1 | 1500 | 2 |
| U1 | 1500 | 3 |
| U2 | 1500 | 1 |
| U2 | 1500 | 2 |
| U3 | 1500 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
select a.*,
row_number()over(partition by user order by payment) as Flag
from table_name a
```

Comment: Note that this is not ANSI SQL compliant. (The `*` must be qualified when combined with something else in the SELECT clause. However, some dbms's don't care about this, while others do.)